# Lock file from being edited or deleted

Tags: centos, files, lock

I have CentOS and cPanel installed. I want to lock certain files (e.g. `.ftpquota`) from being deleted through FTP. I tried to change the ownership  to `root:root` or `root:lock` but it didn't work; neither did changing the mode to 0.

How can I lock the `.ftpquota` file?

Answer (score 10):

If you don't need to modify the file then the `chattr +i` will lock the file from deletion.  This will mark the file immutable.

Otherwise file deletion is controlled by the directory containing the file.  Anyone with write access to the directory can delete most of the files it contains.   Files with the sticky bit set can only be deleted by the owner.  Files with the immutable attribute can not be deleted until the attribute is removed.